# Script to create linear path from bezier path on document grid

Tags: illustrator-scripting, grids, javascript

How do I find the nearest grid point of a bezier path as it intersects the document grid?

I am writing a script to create a linear copy of of a bezier path.  I need to know where the path crosses the grid in-between the anchor points.  Not sure if this can be calculated or not.  Hoping you guys can help.

[image: example linear path on grid from bezier curve path]

Comment: Read [pomax bezier info](https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/)

Comment: Thanks for the great link, reading the information now.

Comment: The more hands on, graphic designer solution would be to fill the Bezier shape, rasterize it at a fitting low resolution without anti-aliasing and then auto-trace it. But I don't know if you need this for an aesthetic or more scientific purpose?

Comment: Thanks @wolff that's a very interesting idea I hadn't thought of.  Not sure if the result will be scientific enough for what I need (nearest grid point along/across each grid line), but I'll definitely give it a shot.

Comment: I just tried to make a 1 inch grid and rasterize a Bezier shape to 1 ppi and it seems to be accurate. [Check out this screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/9e9S8Bk.png). And is it "scientific" enough? I have no way of telling, but Illustrator *is* a program you use to rasterize vector which essentially is what you want to do, so why shouldn't it be? The problem is the auto-tracing though. I can't get a good result. Could be because of the low ppi. I tried upscaling the image before tracing, which works better but with many small inaccuracies. Strangely enough ...

Comment: The screenshot is great, love the accuracy.  The auto trace must work as well or I can't use this technique.  Ooh, so close.  Thanks for the test.  I'm getting some great information from joojaa's bezier link above.  I'm gonna try a few tests with flattening the curve.